# how to autoload with composer.json?

Tags: php, autoload, composer-php

I am using these require statements in my root folder of project directory (in index.php).

```
require("./models/college/collegeModel.php");
require("./routes/routes.php");
require("./controllers/college/collegeController.php");
require("./controllers/home/homeController.php");
require("./controllers/login/loginController.php");
require("./controllers/logout/logoutController.php");
require("./controllers/public/publicController.php");
require("./lib/util.php");
```

and now I am trying to use composer autoload to load on demand by using composer.json file to remove all above require with single one :

```
require("./vendor/autoload.php");
```

My composer.json file is as follows

```
{
    "name": "vermajnv/web",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "vermajnv",
            "email": "nayanrahul.jnv@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["models/college", "controllers/college", 
"controllers/home", "controllers/login", "controllers/logout", 
"controllers/public", "lib/", "routes/"]
    }
}
```

It works fine if I remove **"lib/"** and **"routes/"**

please provide me proper solution for this problem I'll be thankful to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oho.. I got what I was doing wrong

actually the **util.php** and **routes.php** does not contains a class to initialize the **autoload_classmap.php**

my util.php was before like this :

```
<?php

    public function baseUrl($url) {
        $contaxtPath = "/" . explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[1];
        return $contaxtPath . $url;
    }

    public function redirect($to) {
        $url = baseUrl($to);
        header("Location:" . $url, 302);
    }
```

Now I just make it wrapped with a class with **static** methods and these methods can be access through **HTMLutill::**

```
<?php

    class HTMLutil {

// static method inside a class are visible every where without creating instance of class (HTMLutil) we can access it by HTML::baseUrl();
    public static function baseUrl($url) {
        $contaxtPath = "/" . explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[1];
        return $contaxtPath . $url;
    }

    public static function redirect($to) {
        $url = self::baseUrl($to);
        header("Location:" . $url, 302);
    }

}
```

Now my app is working fine.
happy coding guys..